# Wix execute Powershell WixQuietExec64

Tags: powershell, wix

I'm creating an installer with Wix 3.10. This installer will need to execute a PowerShell script after the installation of the files.

To execute the PowerShell script I use the following:

```
<Component Id="AddUserInstallScript" Guid="{87DB934A-5ECF-4073-81F1-BA139F30A686}" Directory="PHONEMANAGER_FOLDER" >
    <File Id="CreateADUserScript" Name="CreateADUser.ps1" Source="CreateADUser.ps1" KeyPath="yes"/>
</Component>

<Property Id="POWERSHELLEXE" Value="c:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell">
</Property>

<Condition Message="This application requires Windows PowerShell.">
    <![CDATA[Installed OR POWERSHELLEXE]]>
</Condition>

<SetProperty Id="RunPSscriptCommand"
    Before="RunPSscriptCommand"
    Sequence="execute"
    Value="&quot;[POWERSHELLEXE]&quot; -Version 3.0 -NonInteractive -NoLogo -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command &quot;&amp;'[#CreateADUserScript]' -domainname '[SERVICE_USER_NETBIOSDOMAIN]' -password '[service_user_pwd]' -domainadminname '[DOMAIN_ADMINISTRATOR]' -domainadminpassword '[domain_administrator_pwd]' ; exit $$($Error.Count)&quot; "
/> 
<CustomAction Id="RunPSscriptCommand" 
            BinaryKey="WixCA" 
            DllEntry="WixQuietExec64"
            Execute="deferred" 
            Return="check" 
            Impersonate="no"/>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="RunPSscriptCommand"  After="InstallFiles"><![CDATA[NOT Installed]]></Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

When I run the installer I'm getting the following error in the log file:

> MSI (s) (10:F8) [09:54:54:515]: Invoking remote custom action.
>   DLL: C:\Windows\Installer\MSI80E7.tmp, Entrypoint: WixQuietExec64
>   WixQuietExec64:  Error 0x80070001: Command line returned an error.
>   WixQuietExec64:  Error 0x80070001: QuietExec64 Failed
>   WixQuietExec64:  Error 0x80070001: Failed in ExecCommon method
>   CustomAction RunPSscriptCommand returned actual error code 1603
>   (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)

On the destination machines is PowerShell 3 installed. The script also uses PowerShell 3 modules. 
I have included the option `-InputFormat None` but this makes no difference for PowerShell 3.

Any thoughts on this issue?

Answer (score -1):

1. Try to run the script stand alone, in order to exclude command errors.
2. I have encountered same problem and what solved it was the command length (in your situation is RunPSscriptCommand's value), I have decreased the length to be less than 255 characters.
3. You can check your powershell version automatically using WixPSExtension.dll

   ```
   <PropertyRef Id="POWERSHELLVERSION" />
   <Condition Message="You must have PowerShell 1.0 or higher.">
     <![CDATA[Installed OR POWERSHELLVERSION >= "1.0"]]>
   </Condition>
   ```

I hope it will help.